# Django 'User' object has no attribute 'user' when combining login_required with user_passes_test

Tags: python, django, decorator, django-authentication

I'm trying to combine a custom `user_passes_test` with a `login_required` decorator.

This works fine:

```
@login_required
@user_passes_test(profile_expired, "Main:profile_expired")
def home(request):
    return render(request, "Main/pages/home.html", {})
```

In helpers.py

```
def profile_expired(user):
    if user.is_authenticated and user.profile.expiration_date is not None:
        return user.profile.expiration_date >= date.today()
    elif user.profile.expiration_date is None:
        return True
    return False
```

If I visit `/app/` and `profile_expired` returns True, I get redirected to `/app/profile_expired`.

However, the very same code on all other views, is returning error...

```
@login_required
@user_passes_test(profile_expired, "Main:profile_expired")
def another_view(request):
    # some code...
    return render(request, "Main/pages/another_page.html", context)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\S\PycharmProjects\SO\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\S\PycharmProjects\SO\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\S\PycharmProjects\SO\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\S\PycharmProjects\SO\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\S\PycharmProjects\SO\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py", line 20, in _wrapped_view
    if test_func(request.user):
  File "C:\Users\S\PycharmProjects\SO\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py", line 20, in _wrapped_view
    if test_func(request.user):
  File "C:\Users\S\PycharmProjects\SO\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 257, in inner
    return func(self._wrapped, *args)
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'user'
```

While `home` has just the code above, `another_view` (and all other views) have more code... But the error cannot be inside the view since I've placed a breakpoint inside of them, started the debugger, and they never get triggered. The error must be somewhere else.

I can't pinpoint why is this happening. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The test_func should take a `user` as its argument.

```
def profile_expired(user):
    return user.profile.expiry_date > date.today()
```

You haven't shown your function, but I suspect that you have written it to take a request, then use `request.user`.

```
def profile_expired(request):
    return request.user.profile.expiry_date > date.today()
```

Comment: Nope, the function takes user as argument (otherwise how could the home function work?) - updating the answer. Thanks for the help though

Comment: Your answer shows that this *is* what's happening. The decorator is using your view `def profile_expired(request)`. The home function works because it is defined earlier so is using the correct test function.

Comment: Oooooh I get it! I gave the helper function and the view the same name!

Answer (score 1):

Somehow, having the `profile_expired` view declared before the views that uses the user_passes_test decorator is what caused the bug.

This will crash `another_page`:

```
@login_required
@user_passes_test(profile_expired, "Main:profile_expired")
def home(request): #...


@login_required
def profile_expired(request): #...


@login_required
@user_passes_test(profile_expired, "Main:profile_expired")
def another_page(request): #...
```

Simply moving `profile_expired` to the bottom solved the issue.

I have no idea why and will accept any answer that explains it.

Comment: Your `profile_expired` view overwrites the `profile_expired` test function. When you define the view earlier in the module, the `user_passes_test` decorator uses the view, which throws the error because it expects a `request`, not a user (as I guessed in my answer). Moving the view to the bottom solves the problem because the decorator uses the test func before it is overwritten, however it is not an ideal fix. It would be better to rename either the test function (e.g. `test_profile_expired`) or the view.